# Why isn't JSON.stringify() passing the data to $.cookie()

Tags: jquery, json, cookies, stringify

This is the code that I've got:

```
var tmp_kana_type = "hiragana";
var tmp_kana_set = "monographs";

cookie_symbols = {"symbols": []};

for (kana_row=0; kana_row<10; kana_row++) {
    for (kana_column=0; kana_column<5; kana_column++) {

        var tmp_JSON  = {
                "kana_type": tmp_kana_type,
                "kana_set": tmp_kana_set,
                "kana_row": kana_row,
                "kana_column": kana_column,
                "selected": 0,
                "correct": 0,
                "total": 0
        };

        cookie_symbols.symbols.push(tmp_JSON);
    }
}

console.log(cookie_symbols); // works

var to_string = JSON.stringify(cookie_symbols);
console.log(to_string); // works

var to_json = JSON.parse(to_string);
console.log(to_json); // works



$.cookie("test_cookie1", "test string"); 
console.log($.cookie("test_cookie1")); // works

$.cookie("test_cookie2", JSON.stringify(cookie_symbols)); // does not work (why?)
console.log($.cookie("test_cookie2")); // does not work (null)
console.log(JSON.parse($.cookie("test_cookie2"))); // does not work (null)
```

JSON.stringfy() is not working with $.cookie() while I believed it should. Did I do something wrong, and how do I fix or make this work? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225030/jquery-save-json-data-object-in-cookie), and it's pretty much what I did too, but in my case it doesn't work for some reason. I am using [this jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/).

Comment: Why not? `to_string` != `to_sting`.

Comment: @Derija93 - I wrote that as an example of what I tried and what worked when I checked it in firebug console. I made a typo here and fixed it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe is your main issue is that you've exceed the [maximum cookie file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107140/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-file).

Comment: I didn't even think about that... I guess I'll have to think of a different approach. Thank you.

Comment: I was just running some tests to verify that this was the correct answer but you beat me to it.

Comment: @pootzko I recommend looking into the `localStorage`. It basically works the same way, except that the storage isn't sent to the server. Thus you are likely not to have to worry about size restrictions.